# Binding android SDK in Xamarin - Meridian

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

I'm a newbie in Xamarin and in the past few days I have been trying to bind the Meridian Android SDK (meridianapps.com). In the documentation the SDK requires 2 external libraries (via gradle) that are:

com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.9
com.squareup:otto:1.3.5

Using the extension [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings) I added this 2 references in the Xamarin project. The volley library initial gives some compiling errors that I solved using the entries in pastebin.com/qqLqy0AA in configurations in the Transforms/Metadata.xml that I found [here](https://github.com/royd/Xamarin.Android.Volley/blob/master/Transforms/Metadata.xml).

The otto library I can't solve the problem and that's why i require some help

In the link pastebin.com/NeNsx29P it´s the output of the compiling of the binding project with the Meridian SDK and the 2 dependencies.

And in the link pastebin.com/V2ia8GVh I try to make the binding with the proper dependencies added

Thank you,
Nuno

Note: Sorry for the links but for now i only can post 2 links per post. Later I will edit the post.

Comment: Please indicate what problem you specifically have with this binding so people aren't just writing this binding for you. I have a guide on this topic that can jump start you further here: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Are you asking how to use a Java lib in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: @nuno407 Did you manage to bind the library in the end ?